# create a matrix with condition in C++

Tags: c++, if-statement, matrix, conditional-statements, line

I want to create a matrix `B` from a matrix `A`, in C++.

First column of `A` is distance `D1`, second column is distance `D2`. Matrix `B` copies the same columns (and rows) of `A`, except when in `A` it happens that `D2-D1=delta` exceeds a threshold. In this case, the row of `A` is break in two rows in `B`.

I wrote an algorithm, but the problem is that it gives `segmentation fault`. Someone can help, why it happens?

```
std::vector<float> newD1(10), newD2(10);
float box=5.;
int j=0;
for(auto i=0;i<D1.size();i++){
    float delta=D2[i]-D1[i];
      if (delta>box){ //break row i in two rows: j and j+1
        //first half of row i goes in row j
        newD1[j]=D1[i];
        newD2[j]=(D1[i]+D2[i])/2.;
        //second half of row i goes in j+1
        D1[j+1]=(D1[i]+D2[i])/2.;
        D2[j+1]=D2[i];
        j=j+2; //we skip two row because we break up the original row in 2 rows
      }
      else{
       newD1[j]=(D1[i]);
       newD2[j]=D2[i];
       j=j+1; //we skip one row because the original row is unchanged
      }
    }
```

Here I give you an example of matrix `A` and `B`; I also specify `delta` beside each line of the matrix.

Matrix `A`:

```
    #D1 D2        delta
    |0   5  |     5
A=  |5   15 |     10   }--> exceed the threshold, delta>5. Must break in 2 rows in `B`
    |15  17 |     2
```

`B` is created breaking the second line in two lines, because delta>5 :

```
      #D1 D2     delta
    |0   5  |     5
B=  |5   10 |     5 }--> created from row #2 of `A`. `D2` is midpoint between`D1` and `D2` in row #2 in `A`
    |10  15 |     5 }--> created from row #2 of `A`. `D1` is midpoint between`D1` and `D2` in row #2 in `A`
    |15  17 |     2
```

```
 EDIT:
```

What if I want to recursively break up the rows (e.g. suppose that at row #2 in `A`, `delta>3*box`, meaning that I need to break up that row in 3 rows in `B`). Any suggestions?

Comment: Use a debugger and carefully look at the values of `j` would be my guess.

Comment: u define the size of the vector to be 10, j can be bigger.

Comment: ok. Thanks, I degugged it and now it works. But there is a problem on the size of newD1, newD2, that I don't know a priori. Is there a way to dynamically define the size? So it adapts along the way . By using std::vector<float> D1; , it gives segmentation fault.

Comment: if you not set size u trying to access using [] to non existing place,  you can use either pushback or define the size before. there is a lot of solutions for you problem, starting from is vector is the correct container for you, resize and etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.You can use push_back to avoid the size definition

2.You updated D1 and D2 instead of newD1 and newD2

```
  #include <vector>
    #include <iostream>
    
    using namespace std;
    
    int main()
    {
        std::vector<float> D1 = { 0,5,15 };
        std::vector<float> D2 = { 5,15,17 };
        std::vector<float> newD1, newD2;
    
        float box = 5.;
        for (auto i = 0; i < D1.size(); i++) {
            float delta = D2[i] - D1[i];
            if (delta > box) { //break row i in two rows: j and j+1
              //first half of row i goes in row j
                newD1.push_back(D1[i]);
                newD2.push_back((D1[i] + D2[i]) / 2.);
                //second half of row i goes in j+1
                newD1.push_back ((D1[i] + D2[i]) / 2.);
                newD2.push_back (D2[i]);
            }
            else {
                newD1.push_back(D1[i]);
                newD2.push_back(D2[i]);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: what if I want to recursively break up the rows (e.g. suppose that D2-D1>3*box) until each (D2-D1<box)?